# Search table for all instances of a word "Yes" in all cells, create row with each "Yes" found in new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to look through a table in a sheet. Find each cell with "Yes" in it, when one is found. Paste a Yes to A1, when another is found A2, etc...

I was trying to modify this code to search all cells instead of just Row A

Comment: Did you forget to include your code?

Comment: There is no row A... what is the logic of pasting "Yes" in A1, A2 etc...

Comment: Is this homework or something?

Answer (score 0):

Following code should give you the headstart

```
Sub Text_search() 
    Dim Myrange As Range 
    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    For Each cell In Myrange
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "YES") > 0 Then
          'do something
       Else
         'do something else
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to @isomericharsh's answer, if it's a table you're looking through, that simplifies defining the range; just use DataBodyRange.

If the table 'Table1' is on 'Sheet1' and the results are to be posted on 'Sheet2' then I'd do as follows:

```
Sub Search_for_Yes()
    Dim YesAmt As Long ' - Amount of yes's found
    YesAmt = 0 'to start with

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    'It's always safer to use specific references rather than ActiveSheet

    For Each cell In ws1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange 'The data in the table excluding headings and totals
        If cell.Value = "YES" Then 'might need to add wildcards to this if you want to include cells that contain yes as part of larger text string. Also note that it's case-specific.
            ws2.Cells(1 + YesAmt, 1).Value = "Yes" 'so that each time a yes is found it will log it further down
            YesAmt = YesAmt + 1
        End If
    Next

    x = MsgBox(YesAmt & " values found and listed", vbOKOnly + vbInformation)

End Sub
```

Does that help?